# help needed for contacting a supervisor for PhD

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor

I have done my Masters research in Microbial ecology. I am interested in stem cell research but I belong to a developing country where we don't have cutting edge research opportunities to gain hand-on experience. I have a good academic background but no research experience except undergraduate and postgraduate research. I am really willing to learn new techniques and want to change my research field to stem cell research. I am not good at convincing and presenting my point to convince a potential supervisor and show my motivation and interest.

Do I have to explain all this to the supervisor I am about to contact to make a point or straight away show my interest? I have obtained a scholarship just need acceptance and secure admission.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent generally, we add discipline-specific tags only if the question is about standards or conventions *specific* to the discipline - not every time someone mentioned their field in the question. Also, the [tag:stem] tag is not about stem cell research (as per its tag wiki excerpt)

Answer (score 1):

If you have funding, you might email him:

> Hello Professor X,
>
> I am interested in researching stem cells, and see you are an expert
>   at researching stem cells. I am wondering if you are accepting new
>   graduate student this application cycle?
>
> My background is QRS and also have some interests in TRV. Your paper
>   on "MMMMM" is interesting, and wonder if your group is going to expand
>   on that paper and if there are any opportunities in this field for
>   graduate students if you are accepting students?
>
> It is also important to note that I have a scholarship that will fully
>   fund my education, and thus, am looking for a place to spend this
>   scholarship money.
>
> Thank you for your time,
>
> Marviii

Your actual email should probably be more specific and formal, but keep it brief. You are essentially a free graduate student (except time), so potential supervisors should be interested in you. Don't be modest about mentioning it.